# Changing label text based on radio button selection

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change the label of a form box based on the selection of a radio button.

After scouring the internet, and multiple coding attempts using multiple variations of code, I've hit a brick wall, because nothing I seem to do works. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

These are the two radio buttons

```
<input type="radio" name="event" id="walkEvent" value="walkEvent"/><label>Walk Event</label>
<input type="radio" name="event" id="otherEvent" value="otherEvent"/><label>Event</label>
```

This is the label I want to change

```
<p><label id="place">Meeting Point/Location: </label><input type="text" name="meeting_or_location"/></p>
```

This is the script I have so far

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

         $(document).ready(function(){

         if ($('#walkEvent').is(':checked')){
             $('#place').text('Meeting Point:');
         }
        else if ($('#otherEvent').is(':checked')){
             $('#place').text('Location:');
         }
        });

    </script>
```

The idea being that if the Walk Event radio button is selected, then the label 'Meeting Point/Location:' becomes 'Meeting Point:'. Conversely, if Event is selected, 'Meeting Point/Location:' becomes 'Location:'

Yet when I use the above code, and check a radio button, nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind listener to `change` event which happens when you click on radio button:

```js
$('[name="event"]').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).attr('id') == 'walkEvent') {
        $('#place').text('Meeting point: ');
    } else {
        $('#place').text('Location: ');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="event" id="walkEvent" value="walkEvent"/><label>Walk Event</label>
<input type="radio" name="event" id="otherEvent" value="otherEvent"/><label>Other Event</label>

<p><label id="place">Meeting Point / Location: </label><input type="text" name="meeting_or_location"/></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `click` event for this,hope this helps

```js
$("input[name='event']").click(function(){
            var radioValue = $("input[name='event']:checked").val();
            if(radioValue=="walkEvent")
            $('#place').html('Meeting Point')
            else
            $('#place').html('Location')
            
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="event" id="walkEvent" value="walkEvent"/><label>Walk Event</label>
<input type="radio" name="event" id="otherEvent" value="otherEvent"/><label>Other Event</label>
<p><label id="place">Meeting Point / Location: </label><input type="text" name="meeting_or_location"/></p>
```